# Adding a caption to a non-float environment with figures and equations

Tags: captionof

I have the following:

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{split}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{option 3 dynamics.png}
  \end{split}
  \hfill
  \begin{split}
    \dot{m}_A = \alpha_0 + \alpha \left( \frac{1}{1 + p_C^n} * \frac{1}{1 + p_A^n} \right) - m_A\\
    \dot{m}_B = \alpha_0 + \frac{\alpha}{1 + p_A^n} - m_B\\
    \dot{m}_C = \alpha_0 + \frac{\alpha}{1+p_B^n} - m_C
  \end{split}
\end{align*}
```

and would like to add a caption to this.  I tried using \captionof but don't know how to grab onto it since it's not a table or figure or equation.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Will this be the *only* such equation with a caption, or will it be one of many?  And, if one of many, do you want the captions to be identified with a running equation number?  As in `Equation 37: the equivalence of mass and energy.`

Comment: There will be about 6 of these.  I would ideally like them to be identified with a figure number starting from where the last figure ended - if that's possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}`  after the `align*`. It will keep the numbering of the figures.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[labelfont=sf]{caption}  

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{The last image so far.}\label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}
    
\begin{align*}
    \begin{split}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{split}
    \hfill
    \begin{split}
        \dot{m}_A &= \alpha_0 + \alpha \left( \frac{1}{1 + p_C^n} * \frac{1}{1 + p_A^n} \right) - m_A\\
        \dot{m}_B &= \alpha_0 + \frac{\alpha}{1 + p_A^n} - m_B\\
        \dot{m}_C &= \alpha_0 + \frac{\alpha}{1+p_B^n} - m_C
    \end{split}
\end{align*}    
\captionof{figure}{Graphical illustration and the Model}\label{fig:b}

\bigskip    
    
The Model is shown in the figure  \ref{fig:b}.  

\end{document}
```

`\caption{<text>}` can only be used inside floats and is a native LaTeX command.

`\captionof{<float type>}{<text>}`can be used outside of floats and is provided by the `caption` package.
Very useful when you want to attach a caption to a non-floating environment like in this case.